# ValueError: Contour levels must be increasing - how to plot 3 feature data

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(0,1,[100,3])

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

z = data[:,2]

plt.contour([x,y],z)
```

When I run this code with dummy data I get:

```
ValueError: Contour levels must be increasing
```

Do you have any idea what would this mean and how I could fix it?

Comment: ``plt.contour` expects its input on a grid. You might try `plt.tricontour(x,y,z)` for unsorted input.

Comment: @JohanC, I was just typing an answer with this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.contour` is a bit particular about its input, the z values must be on values on a rectangular 2D grid, see for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.expand_dims(np.arange(1,11,1), axis=1)
y = np.expand_dims(np.arange(2,21,2), axis=0)
z = y * x

print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)
print(z.shape)

plt.figure()
plt.contour(z)
plt.show()
```

You can also provide x and y values for `plt.contour` by using `np.meshgrid` :

```
XX,YY = np.meshgrid(x,y)
plt.figure()
plt.contour(XX, YY, z)
plt.show()
```

If you have z-values with irregular values for x and y, you might use `plt.tricontour`, see the following example:

```
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation

data = np.random.normal(0,1,[100,3])
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
#z = data[:,2]
z = x * y

tri = Triangulation(x,y)

plt.figure()
plt.tricontour(tri, z, )
plt.scatter(x,y, c=z)
plt.show()
```

Edit: from JohanC's comment i learned that this can be simplified without importing `matplotlib.tri` by:

```
plt.figure()
plt.tricontour(x,y,z)
plt.scatter(x,y, c=z)
plt.show()
```